# How do I quit multiple versions of Firefox with Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have two versions of firefox. One has an application name "Firefox" and the other is called "Firefox 2".

I'd like to tell AppleScript to close both instances of Firefox. Here's my code

```
tell application "Firefox" to quit
tell application "Firefox 2" to quit
```

It's weird because I can type this into Script Editor, but when I press save it always turns into this.

```
tell application "Firefox" to quit
tell application "Firefox" to quit
```

[image]

How do I make sure they both close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying and renaming the copy of the original **Firefox** *application bundle* to **Firefox 2**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me to gracefully quit each occurrence of **Firefox**:

```
set fx1 to "Firefox"
set fx2 to "Firefox 2"

tell application fx1 to quit
delay 2
tell application fx2 to quit
```

In the screenshot below you can see in the **Replies** *pane* that each occurrence of **Firefox** returned `--> error number 0`, **which is a graceful quit**! Any *error number* other then `0` means something went wrong.

[image: Script Editor window]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfF96.png) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>